# How do I overload operators for WPF containers?

Tags: wpf, f#

```
type AdderType() =
    /// Appends to the container.
    static member (+)
        (cont:DockPanel,child:#UIElement) =
        cont.Children.Add child |> ignore
        child
```

When I make the class like the above and try something like this.

```
let dock = DockPanel()
let win = Window(Title = "Check the Window Style", Content = dock)
let menu = dock + Menu()
```

I get the error `None of the types 'DockPanel,Menu' support the operator '+'.` I was inspired to make the above by [Phil Trelford's](http://trelford.com/blog/post/F-operator-overloads-for-WPF-dependency-properties.aspx) binding example which goes like this:

```
type DependencyPropertyValuePair(dp:DependencyProperty,value:obj) =
    member this.Property = dp
    member this.Value = value
    static member (+) 
        (target:#UIElement,pair:DependencyPropertyValuePair) =
        target.SetValue(pair.Property,pair.Value)
        target
```

The above for some reason works. I have no idea why. Would it be possible to overload the `+` or some other operator so that I could elegantly add controls to containers?

Comment: You can always do a global overload of the operator - but you rpobably dont want + in that case

Comment: I tried overloading `++` and `|+`, but it did not work.

Comment: And `%+%` just now. I doubt `-` would work. Is there some trick to this?

Comment: I basically meant what Tomas' answer is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operators defined inside a class only work if one of the arguments is an instance of the class, but you can define your operator as a global operator:

```
let (++) (cont:DockPanel) (child:#UIElement) =
    cont.Children.Add child |> ignore
    child
```

The following should then work:

```
let dock = DockPanel()
let win = Window(Title = "Check the Window Style", Content = dock)
let menu = dock ++ Menu()
```

But to be honest, I don't think this kind of problem is a good place for using custom operators. Using `+` here is confusing, because you are not really *adding* two things in any sense. Your operator is not commutative, e.g. `(a ++ b) <> (b ++ a)`.

I think a more idiomatic code would be to define a named function and use the `|>`:

```
let appendTo (cont:DockPanel) (child:#UIElement) =
    cont.Children.Add child |> ignore
    child

let dock = DockPanel()
let win = Window(Title = "Check the Window Style", Content = dock)
let menu = Menu() |> appendTo dock
```

Comment: I'd change the `(cont:DockPanel)` to `(cont:Panel)` since the supertype has the `Children` property as well. Apart from that I am satisfied with this.

Comment: +1 : Using + here is confusing, because you are not really adding two things in any sense. Your operator is not commutative, e.g. (a ++ b) <> (b ++ a).

Comment: I don't think it is a problem that the operator is not commutative. String concatenation is not commutative (``"Hello " + "world" <> "world" + "Hello ") and uses + operator. But I do think that not being associative, e.g. (a + b) + c <> a + (b + c), is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it similarly as in the last example would be like this:

```
type ContainerType(con:Panel) =
    member this.Children = con.Children
    static member (+)
        (child:#UIElement,cont:ContainerType) =
        cont.Children.Add child |> ignore
        child

let toCon = ContainerType
```

Actually I do like Tomas's solution better. And Phil Trelford's example looks so much like it is a part of .NET that it slipped my mind that one of the arguments in the `static member (+)` has `DependencyPropertyValuePair` as the type which is why the `+` operator could be overloaded in the first place. So that answers that.